# jQuery-File-Upload: validate with basic version

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

I want to use the [basic version of jQuery-File-Upload](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/basic.html) and validate the input (I only want to upload certain types with constrains on the size).

So, if I apply the option `acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,` I would expect that only images are uploadable. To my surprise, the `acceptFileTypes` option is ignored and I still can upload any files (like `test.tar` for example).

Is it not possible to validate input with the basic version? Here is my changed code ( I only added `acceptFileTypes` and `maxFileSize` to the basic example).

```
$(function () {
    'use strict';
    // Change this to the location of your server-side upload handler:
    var url = 'server/php/';
    $('#fileupload').fileupload({
        url: url,
        dataType: 'json',
        acceptFileTypes: /(\.|\/)(gif|jpe?g|png)$/i,
        maxFileSize: 999000,
        done: function (e, data) {
            $.each(data.result.files, function (index, file) {
                $('<p/>').text(file.name).appendTo('#files');
            });
        },
        progressall: function (e, data) {
            var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
            $('#progress .progress-bar').css(
                'width',
                progress + '%'
            );
        }
    }).prop('disabled', !$.support.fileInput)
        .parent().addClass($.support.fileInput ? undefined : 'disabled');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the script only accpets the changes after I clear the cache. Now the validation works.